# PHPExcel drawing new lines when combining sheets

Tags: cakephp, phpexcel

I'm combining about 20 excel sheets (user uploaded) using PHPExcel into a report. This is done by using this bit of code:

```
$filename = APP . 'docs' . DS . 'reports' . DS . $Workbooks[0]['Report']['company'] . '.' . $Workbooks[0]['Report']['report_name'] . '.' . $Workbooks[0]['Report']['extension'];
$blacklist = array('Company Organogram');
$MasterFile = $this->PhpExcel->createMasterFile($filename,$company . '.' . $title,$colour);
foreach($Workbooks as $Workbook) :
    if(!in_array($Workbook['Report']['report_name'],$blacklist)) {
        $file = APP . 'docs' . DS . 'reports' . DS . $Workbook['Report']['company'] . '.' . $Workbook['Report']['report_name'] . '.' . $Workbook['Report']['extension'];
        $MasterFile = $this->PhpExcel->addExternalWorksheet($MasterFile,$file,$company . '.' . $title,$colour);
        #unlink($file);
    }
endforeach;
$this->PhpExcel->saveToDisk(APP . 'docs' . DS . 'reports' . DS . 'Weekly Reports for Week ' . (date('W') + 1) . '.xlsx',$MasterFile);
```

I'm working with CakePHP, so there is a helper. `saveToDisk` simply saves the file to the disc after which it is attached and sent to a mailing list.

All the above works fine. But I'm having issues where the combining process draws in extra lines. For instance, this:

[image]

becomes this:

[image]

How would I fix this? Is there something I should set so it doesn't draw in all the lines?

Comment: there might be a style telling all columns and rows after D3 to have borders? depends exactly what your `PhpExcel` component is doing in your `createMasterFile()` and `addExternalWorksheet()` methods. can you post that code?

Comment: Not all the files have the same borders at the same place.